# write a file and make it read only

Tags: c, linux, file-io

I write a database for students in C under Linux. So after entering my data and after closing the program, the data will be saved automatically in a text-file. How can I make this file read only? I will later add a function that will read the data from the file, so only the program can process data. Any user who opens the file can only read data but he has no rights to change the data in the file. In other words how can I make my saved data secure?
Here is some code:

```
void writeData(){
    FILE * fpw;
    fpw=fopen("database.txt","wb");
    if(fpw==NULL){
       printf("the file cannot be opened");
       exit(1);
    }
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
        fprintf(fpw,"%s, %s, %d, %s , %s;\n",   
            (db+i)->lastname,(db+i)->firstname,(db+i)->mNr, (db+i)->subject, (db+i)->nationality);
    }
    fclose(fpw);
}
```

I wrote an example. Here is the code:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char mode[]="111";
    int in=strtol(mode,0,8);
    int ret_value=chmod("./file.csv",in);
    if(ret_value!=0){
        printf("failed to change mode");
       }
   }
```

But I want that only the program has the rw-rights. The rest must only have read-rights including me as a terminal-user. How can do it? 
I think, I will try to read about Setuid and to use it

Comment: The program should run with effective UID which is given the write access to the file. See `setuid`.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: As long as you are on Linux and your students are also on Linux you could just use `chmod` on the created file from the command line. If you want or need to do it in `C` code you can also use `chmod()` by including  `#include <sys/stat.h>`.  See `man 2 chmod` for this. The protoype is `int chmod(const char *pathname, mode_t mode);`.

Comment: @donjuedo The OS is specified in the question.

Comment: Yup, I went back and read too fast.

Comment: Note: Curious to open a _binary_ file and write text.  Recommend  `"w"` instead.  No diff with Linux - yet more portable.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`chmod`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/chmod) in C to change the mode of file.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

int chmod(const char *path, mode_t mode);
```

The following example sets read permissions for the owner, group, and others.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

const char *path;
...
chmod(path, S_IRUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH);
```

If you want to read the permissions, use stat.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

int stat(const char * restrict path, struct stat * restrict buf);
```